# Spyder not showing every variable in variable explorer

Tags: python, dataframe

since I am not finding anything on google related to my "problem" I ask you all here. I am using the Spyder IDE for scientific coding with Python 3.7, my problem is spider does not showing data frame variable in variable explorer.
for example :

```
 word_mi_information.append([average, max_mi, class_name[max_index], vocab_list[w_index]])
    
word_mi_information = sorted(word_mi_information, key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)

preview3 = pd.DataFrame(word_mi_information)
preview3.columns=['mutual information(MI)', 'main class MI', 'main_class', 'word']

preview3.head(10)

#the expected output 


    Info Gain                 main class        info main_class                                 word
0   4473.658680600584   24124.9834859362     ('C:/Users/user/Desktop/Akhbarona\\Tech', '', '')  هتف
1   4154.761699928653   20292.13826441525   ('C:/Users/user/Desktop/Akhbarona\\Tech', '', '')   خدم
2   4082.1526400011394  21332.74626781158   ('C:/Users/user/Desktop/Akhbarona\\Tech', '', '')   شرك
3   3907.930114110117   7164.627960061558   ('C:/Users/user/Desktop/Akhbarona\\Politics', '', '')   غرب
4   3487.537345717307   17568.034002235207  ('C:/Users/user/Desktop/Akhbarona\\Medical', '', '')    جسم
5   3469.0442804650042  17593.549747242403  ('C:/Users/user/Desktop/Akhbarona\\Medical', '', '')    نول
6   3398.1096950558563  17168.788976051695  ('C:/Users/user/Desktop/Akhbarona\\Medical', '', '')    صحة
7   3392.971784676107   17108.75969342166   ('C:/Users/user/Desktop/Akhbarona\\Medical', '', '')    مرض
8   3237.043207698965   15843.821383151355  ('C:/Users/user/Desktop/Akhbarona\\Tech', '', '')   جهز
9   2923.039707389109   24649.83000746686   ('C:/Users/user/Desktop/Akhbarona\\Religion', '', '')   الل
10  2896.6926629600543  15641.256964593376  ('C:/Users/user/Desktop/Akhbarona\\Tech', '', '')   ذكة
```

Comment: Needs a small example to demonstrate what the specific problem is for the question to be answerable

Comment: Please see [How to provide a reproducible copy of your DataFrame using `df.head(30).to_clipboard(sep=',')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246), then **[edit] your question**, and paste the clipboard into a code block. Always provide a [mre] **with code, data, errors, current output, and expected output, as text**. Only plot images are okay.

Comment: actually I don't have errors, I just want to show data frame variable in variable explorer to show output

Comment: I give you the expected output

Comment: How can anyone answer the question without the initial data?

Comment: sorry @TrentonMcKinney I give the expected output

Answer (score 10):

You can try the following: select the "Preferences" option in Spyder and there the "Variable explorer" option. Try unchecking the different options. It worked for me on visualization and filtering.

Comment: this was what I was looking for in the first place when I had the same question. @user14203379 could you mark this as solved if this was also your solution?

Comment: I had to uncheck "Exclude callables and modules" to get any variables (ints, strings, etc.) to show in the Variable Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I answered what I think is the [same question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66761124/spyder-4-2-3-not-showing-function-variables/).

I'm assuming you mean the variable explorer frame stays empty instead of displaying all the variables?
You need to make sure the [correct version of spyder-kernels](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/troubleshooting/common-illnesses.html) is installed in the environment Spyder is install in. From the link:

| Spyder | Spyder-Kernels |
| --- | --- |
| 4.0.0-4.0.1 | 1.8.1 |
| 4.1.0-4.1.2 | 1.9.0 |
| 4.1.3 | 1.9.1 |
| 4.1.4 | 1.9.3 |
| 4.1.5-4.1.6 | 1.9.4 |
| 4.2.0 | 1.10.0 |
| 5.0.0-5.0.5 | 2.0.5 |
| 5.1.0-5.1.5 | 2.1.3 |
| 5.2.0-5.2.1 | 2.2.0 |
| 5.2.2 | 2.2.1 |

If using conda:

```
conda activate ENVIRONEMENT-NAME
conda install spyder-kernels=<VERSION>
```

If not using conda, activate the environment however you usually would and run:

```
pip install spyder-kernels==<VERSION>
```